# Can NetBeans be told to not reformat single-line javadoc comments?

Tags: java, netbeans, formatting, comments

Occasionally, I leave a comment like this above a class field:

```
/** absolute path */
private String path;
```

Now, this is a trivial example and I could easily avoid the need for this comment by naming it absPath, but there are much less well known and more cumbersome field names: for those, a short, although not completely intuitive name is often practical, so a javadoc comment like the one above makes the meaning very clear for newcomers to the project.

My problem is that the NetBeans autoformatter will convert it to the extremely space-wasting, importance-overrating form below:

```
/**
 * absolute path
 */
private String path;
```

The only alternative that I see is to disable comment reformatting altogether, but I want comment reformating: I just don't want this particular kind of reformatting.

Is there a way to have my cake and eat it, too?

Answer (score 0):

you could comment like this

```
// absolute path
private String path;
```

Comment: My comment of orgq3masch's answer applies.

Answer (score -1):

I may be completely off, but i looked into Tools->Options->Editor->Formatting (Java) (Comments) - i hope you find that, there is an example for how to achieve what i believe you want...

/* commeting comment */

i think the difference is one star in the beginning of your comment - hope it works...

Comment: This is a plain block comment, i.e. it doesn't get interpreted by the IDE as a javadoc comments, so e.g. hovering over the variable in code doesn't show the description written in the block comment. That said, a setting like the one above, only for /** */ comments is exactly what I'm looking for.